# The name of red box for packaging coca cola bottles

Tags: image-identification

What is the red plastic box (shown in the image below) called in English? It is used for packaging coca cola bottles, and holds about 24 of them.

[image: stack of red plastic boxes holding empty coca cola bottles]

Comment: Hi new user.  This site IS NOT for questions like this.  You're looking for the excellent English Learning site.  https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Fattie So as a monolingual, native English speaker, you're telling me that if I don't know the word for something, then I should go learn a second language, and then ask my question on ELL? Because ELL's description clearly says, "Q&A for speakers of other languages learning English".

Comment: Hi @KennethK. I would say, (1) it would be highly unusual if you or I did not know the word for this (2) it is, simply, definitely, a question for ELL ("What's the word for this obvious object?")  (3) In the unusual case that you or I couldn't remember that word, I think yeah you'd ask on ELL.  I would certainly ask on ELL if there was some very basic dictionary question I had. But it's hugely hypothetical.  Just because ELL's description says "ABC" it **does not mean you can ask totally off topic questions on here**, I'd say.

Comment: The comment thread is reserved for friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the question, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: This site accepts word requests. Word requests may be closed until enough information is given in the question. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. In the case of a word request, that means the question includes details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. It includes the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provides the exact enclosing sentence or passage.

Comment: @Fattie It is not wrong to refer a person to ELL, but ELL is not our trashcan, and ELL has similar prior research requirements to ELU. It is an expert Q&A site for people who teach or are learning English.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They are *crates*.

The [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/crate):

> a. A container, such as a slatted wooden case, used for storing or shipping.
>   b. A container, usually of plastic, metal, or wood, used to house or transport an animal.

In this case it's meaning (a), though it is nowadays usually plastic to transport bottles.

Comment: The comment thread is reserved for friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the answer, relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. Please avoid debate in comments.